# Order a postgreSQL query on a rolling period

Tags: sql, postgresql

it will be easier if i illustrate my question with a concrete example.

my query (postgresql) :

```
SELECT 
    type.name_type as type_name,
    extract(day from event.creation_date) as days,
    count(0) as number
FROM event, type, event_type
WHERE event.id = event_type.event_id
    AND type.type_id = event_type.type_id
GROUP BY days, type_name;
```

i would like to order the result according to a rolling month. let me explain :

-> let's say we are currently the 6th of whatever month

-> i want the table returned to be ordered on a month according to this day, which means from the 7th to the 6th (current day)

anyone has an idea of how I could do that ?

any help is appreciated :)  have a nice day!

(PS : if these explications aren't enough, i'll try my best to be more specific)

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly , you want to order by date :

```
SELECT 
    type.name_type as type_name,
    extract(day from event.creation_date) as days,
    count(0) as number
FROM event, type, event_type
WHERE event.id = event_type.event_id
    AND type.type_id = event_type.type_id
GROUP BY days, type_name
order by min(event.creation_date) desc
```

Comment: okk, the only issue with your answer is that i would have to put months in the group by clause, and i don't want to ^^(it causes pb of visualization in metabase)
is there another way ?

Comment: @ArmandViolle , see updated answer , how about this query?

Comment: ok the issue now is with metabase graphs options, but the sql query is solid, thank you!

Comment: i've still not a problem with the result of the query. it is well ordered according to dates but there are several line with the same daysvalue (i want them grouped together, like a key in the returned table). any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: @ArmandViolle , that's a different question , ask a new question and provide sample data and desired output